# Why Reference Counters All Start with +1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

As per [swift/stdlib/public/SwiftShims/RefCount.h](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d1c87f3c936c41418ee93320e42d523b3f51b6df/stdlib/public/SwiftShims/RefCount.h):

```
- The strong RC is stored as an extra count: when the physical field is 0 the logical value is 1.
- The unowned RC also has an extra +1 on behalf of the strong references
- The weak RC also has an extra +1 on behalf of the unowned references
```

I'm wondering why an object initialises with +1 to all counters, what's the point of making extras?

Comment: I have posted my best guess as answer. If you want a more authoritative answer, try asking on [the official Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org/), where the actual authors of that `RefCount.h` file sometimes respond.

Answer (score 6):

The `unowned` count is stored in the object's directly-allocated storage. When an `unowned` reference is destroyed, the runtime decrements the `unowned` count. If the decremented count is still above zero, the runtime knows that there is still at least one `strong` or `unowned` reference to the object, so the runtime knows it should not deallocate the object's storage. (The storage remains allocated until all `strong` and `unowned` references to the object are destroyed.) So, when the runtime destroys an `unowned` reference, it doesn't have to check the `strong` count to know whether to deallocate the storage. This saves time in the case where all `unowned` references are destroyed before the last `strong` reference is destroyed.

The `weak` count is stored in the object's “side table” entry, which isn't allocated until it's needed (which is usually when the first `weak` reference to the object is created). When a `weak` reference is destroyed, the runtime decrements the `weak` count. If the decremented count is still above zero, the runtime knows that there is still at least one `strong` or `unowned` or `weak` reference to the object, so the runtime knows it should not deallocate the side table entry for the object. (The side table entry remains allocated until all `strong`, `unowned`, and `weak` references to the object are destroyed.)   So, when the runtime destroys a `weak` reference, it doesn't have to check the `unowned` count (or the `strong` count) to know whether to deallocate the side table entry. This saves time in the case where all `weak` references are destroyed before the last `unowned` (or `strong`) reference is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you! So generally you assume that this is a performance matter, did I got that right? But do the runtime really need this, as (well, at least per [this](https://maximeremenko.com/swift-arc-weak-references) source) side table keeps all reference counters: `strong`, `weak` and `unowned`?

@robmayoff

Comment: I've made a [post on Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-reference-counters-all-start-with-1/42372) as you suggested, and will summarise the discussion here as answers come in.